# SQL Sum Multiple Rows Without Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I have a query that correctly gets the sums and counts of the number of teams and number of people at an event. However, there can be multiple events at the same location on a single date, so I'm attempting to get a Sum of the total number of people at all events at a single location on a single day. 
Here's the query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT 
loc_name, 
eventDate, 
COUNT(t_ID) as Number_of_Teams, 
SUM(NbrOfPeople) as Number_of_People
FROM tblEventDate
WHERE 
eventID = 1 
and eventDate >='09/01/2013'
GROUP BY loc_name, eventDate
ORDER BY eventDate, loc_name
```

A sample dataset looks like this

```
loc_name |eventDate |Number_of_Teams |Number_of_people
TCC      |2013-09-04|12              |38
SMF      |2013-09-04|8               |12
```

This query, however, only gets me the Teams and People numbers where eventID = 1. I need to be able to get a sum where eventID IN (1,2,3,4,5) (maximum of 5 events per location per day) without having to include eventID in the GROUP BY clause. I'm a little bit stumped.

I've tried CASE WHEN expressions, but that requires eventID in the GROUP BY which ultimately separates the value like this dataset.

```
loc_name |eventDate |eventID |Number_of_Teams |Number_of_people
TCC      |2013-09-04|1       |12              |38
TCC      |2013-09-04|2       |9               |22
SMF      |2013-09-04|1       |8               |12
SMF      |2013-09-04|2       |4               |9
SMF      |2013-09-04|3       |13              |31
```

I've also tried nesting SELECT statements, but that was an abject failure. :-)

Ultimately, I need a dataset that looks like:

```
loc_name |eventDate |Number_of_Teams |Number_of_people
TCC      |2013-09-04|21              |60
SMF      |2013-09-04|25              |52
```

Notice that the Number_of_Teams is the full count of all teams across all events at the location on that day, and the Number_of_People is the full sum of all the members of each team across all events at that location on that day.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What about `WHERE eventID IN (1,2,3,4,5)`  instead of `WHERE eventID = 1`?

Comment: Ohh, goodness. I answered my own bloody question in the question. That answer was so simple and staring me in the face the entire time. 
Thanks, Juan.

Comment: [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) for the win! (kinda you did ask the question)

Comment: @xQbert I think he talk to the duck while written the question, but the duck wast paying attention :/.

Comment: Why is `COUNT(t_ID) as Number_of_Teams,` instead of `SUM()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well looks like my comment already solve it, but I was already doing this in case the problem is you didn't know what are the `event_id` for each date

The trick is select up to 5 events from each `loc_name, eventDate` In this case I select the ones with more teams. You are free to add any filter you want.

```
 with cte as ( 
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_name, eventDate 
                                   ORDER BY Number_of_Teams DESC) as rn
      FROM tblEventDate
      WHERE eventDate >='09/01/2013'
 )
 SELECT loc_name, 
        eventDate, 
        COUNT(t_ID) as Number_of_Teams, 
        SUM(NbrOfPeople) as Number_of_People
 FROM cte
 WHERE rn <= 5
 GROUP BY loc_name, eventDate
 ORDER BY eventDate, loc_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If 2012+, you can use the window function sum() over()

**Example**

```
Select Distinct 
       loc_name
      ,eventDate        = max(eventDate)        over (Partition By loc_name)
      ,Number_of_Teams  = sum(Number_of_Teams)  over (Partition By loc_name)
      ,Number_of_people = sum(Number_of_people) over (Partition By loc_name)
 From  YourTable
 Where eventDate>='2013-09-01'
```

**Returns**

```
loc_name    eventDate   Number_of_Teams Number_of_people
SMF         2013-09-04  25              52
TCC         2013-09-04  21              60
```

Comment: I think you also need `partition by eventDate`, still dont know why is this better than group by.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza updated with max(eventDate) assuming OP wanted last date

Comment: I see how that improve the answer. But you still add some `ORDER BY` for the cumulative `MAX()` work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Perhaps your seeing something that I'm not.  I see no need for the Order By.  We're getting the max date filtered by the WHERE.

Comment: I see in the OP question the `event_date`  is part of the `GROUP BY` so my guess he need the result for each day. I thought you were using the `MAX()` to emulate the `GROUP BY` and for that you need `ORDER BY event_date` . But nevermind looks like op only need `IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

Answer (score 0):

You should just change your where clause

```
SELECT 
loc_name, 
eventDate, 
COUNT(t_ID) as Number_of_Teams, 
SUM(NbrOfPeople) as Number_of_People
FROM tblEventDate
WHERE 
eventID IN (1,2,3,4,5) 
and eventDate >='09/01/2013'
GROUP BY loc_name, eventDate
ORDER BY eventDate, loc_name
```